# How to extract a value after splitting a JSON String in Node-RED

Tags: javascript, node-red

I am injecting a String into my flow, then making it into a JSON String with the JSON node and splitting it with the split node. I get 5 messages out of this split node because there are 5 values with 5 properties. What I need is to extract only one of the values, to then use it in a function node. How can I do this?

[image]

This is a picture of one of the 5 outputs. What I want is to ONLY use the value (137) in a function node that should come after the split node. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do nothing.

You just access the value as `msg.payload` in the function node.

Answer (score 0):

```
msg.payload.energy_wh
```

This will access the value in the function node.

Comment: That does not match the image of the object you posted.

Comment: There is no `msg.payload.energy_wh` object in the image of the object you posted so there is no way anybody could get to that answer.